# Formulário de perguntas com radio button retornando exibindo vazio

Tags: php, mysqli

Boa noite,
 Preciso fazer um sistema de perguntas (um questionario) exatamente como esse:
    https://jsfiddle.net/hmana2sL/

Só que preciso que quanto as perguntas e as opções de respostas venham do banco.
 Eu tentei dessa forma só que os radios estão saindo vazios, mais a consulta esta ok, e rodando-a no MySQL ela 
 retorna corretamente os dados, acho que pode ser algo com os loop's, alguém poderia me ajudar a encontrar o erro?:

Segue codigo:

```
     <?php
     //CONEXÃO
$servername = "127.0.0.1"; $username = "root"; $password = "root"; $dbname = "master";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);  
         if ($conn->connect_error) {
             die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
         }
     //CONEXÃO

      $QPergunta  = "SELECT sug_perg_id AS ID_PERGUNTA, sug_perg_pergunta AS PERGUNTA FROM sugestoes_perguntas WHERE sug_perg_area = 3";
      $QAvalicao  = "SELECT sug_aval_id AS ID_AVALIACAO, sug_aval_desc AS DESCRICAO FROM sugestoes_avaliacao";
      $RPergunta  = $conn->query($QPergunta);
      $RAvaliacao = $conn->query($sql);
          while($row = $RPergunta->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "PERGUNTA :".$row["PERGUNTA"];
            echo"<br>";
            while($row = $RAvaliacao->fetch_assoc()){
             echo"<input type='radio' name='".$row["ID_PERGUNTA"]."' value='".$row["ID_AVALIACAO"]."'>".$row["DESCRICAO"];
              echo"<br>";
          }
      }

     //FINALIZA CONEXÃO

        $conn->close();

     //FINALIZA CONEXÃO
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<?php
//CONEXÃO
   $servername = "127.0.0.1"; $username = "root"; $password = "root"; $dbname = "master";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);  
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//CONEXÃO

$QPergunta  = "SELECT sug_perg_id AS ID_PERGUNTA, sug_perg_pergunta AS PERGUNTA FROM sugestoes_perguntas WHERE sug_perg_area = 3";
$QAvalicao  = "SELECT sug_aval_id AS ID_AVALIACAO, sug_aval_desc AS DESCRICAO FROM sugestoes_avaliacao";
$RPergunta  = $conn->query($QPergunta);
$RAvaliacao = $conn->query($QAvalicao);

$Repostas = [];
while($Repostas[] = $RAvaliacao->fetch_assoc());

while($row_pergunta = $RPergunta->fetch_assoc()){
 echo "PERGUNTA :".$row["PERGUNTA"];
 echo"<br>";
 foreach ($Repostas as $row_resposta) {
  echo"<input type='radio' name='".$row_pergunta["ID_PERGUNTA"]."' value='".$row_resposta["ID_AVALIACAO"]."'>".$row_resposta["DESCRICAO"];
  echo"<br>";
 }
}

//FINALIZA CONEXÃO

$conn->close();

//FINALIZA CONEXÃO
?>
```

Isso provavelmemte irá resolver seu problema.

A variável $sql não existe, foi troquei por $QAvalicao;

O segundo problema é o seguinte, você fez somente uma chamada de banco para pegar as respostas. Quando o primeiro while sai do primeiro registro isso significa que o segundo while (mais interno) já leu todos os registros de respostas, então depois da primeira pergunta, não haverá respostas.

Assim, desta forma eu guardei os registros de respostas em uma variavel:

```
$Repostas = [];
while($Repostas[] = $RAvaliacao->fetch_assoc());
```

E Depois para cada registro de Pergunta percorro esta variável com o foreach;

Terceiro erro, a variável $row estava se repetindo e quando erá chamada pelo segundo while em $row["ID_PERGUNTA"] ela iria retorna um valor vazio, pois nesse ponto do código a variável $row só tinha os dados da resposta e não da pergunta.
Para isso renomeei as variáveis para $row_pergunta e $row_resposta.
Especificar o nome de cara variável precisamente com o nome mais próximo do que era guarda é uma ótima pratica de código. Ajuda a você entender um código depois de muito tempo sem ver ele e ainda ajuda em projetos em equipe.

Ps:

```
while($Repostas[] = $RAvaliacao->fetch_assoc());
```

Este While não esta vazio, ele esta preenchendo a variável $Respostas com os registros das respostas. Apesar de a pessoa no comentário abaixo não perceber, o comando dentro da condicional do while esta atribuindo o fetch ao $Repostas[].
Ao usar a expressão [] em um array o php criar um novo índice e atribui o valor a ele. A atribuição retorna este valor ao condicional do while. quando essa atribuição for null, o while para.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Por quê isso possivelmente resolverá o problema? Perceba que o SOpt não é um sistema de suporte, mas sim uma comunidade para programadores profissionais e entusiastas. O objetivo principal é criar conteúdo de qualidade que serve de referência. Uma resposta somente com códigos passa longe disso, então por favor, edite sua resposta explicando o que estava errado no código da pergunta e qual foi a solução adotada, se é a única solução, se é a melhor solução, porquê é a melhor, etc. Aliás, por quê um `while` vazio para criar a lista de respostas? Isso me parece completamente desnecessário.

Comment: Ok, Obrigado, editando...

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Editado, e expliquei o porquê do while "vazio". Beijos.

Comment: Muito melhor. Tome isso como um padrão para respostas futuras. Aliás, o `while` continua vazio. O fato da condição executar algo não muda o fato dele estar vazio. Lembrando que vazio não é o mesmo que "não está fazendo nada". Para este caso, você pode utilizar a função `mysqli_fetch_all`, que é otimizada internamente.